# I'm unable to build and run angular application: 'An unhandled exception occurred: NGCC failed.' has anyone got suggestions on how to resolve this?

Tags: angular, compiler-errors, angular-cli, unhandled-exception

I was able to run this absolutely fine, I then installed Popper via npm and the issue occurred! Full error log below:

```
[error] Error: NGCC failed.
    at NgccProcessor.process (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\ngcc_processor.js:69:19)
    at C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:576:31
    at SyncHook.eval [as call] (eval at create (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:19:10), <anonymous>:7:1)
    at SyncHook.lazyCompileHook (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
    at Object.webpack [as webpackFactory] (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\webpack\lib\webpack.js:55:30)
    at createWebpack (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:21:36)
    at Object.runWebpackDevServer (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-webpack\src\webpack-dev-server\index.js:47:12)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.project (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:164:32)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber._next (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\rxjs\internal\operators\switchMap.js:49:27)
    at SwitchMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Subscriber.js:66:18)
    at C:\Users\alexm\source\repos\JordanSpencer.Ang.Web\JordanSpencer\node_modules\rxjs\internal\util\subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

If anyone has suggestions on how to resolve it'd be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like a Version mismatch. I would recommend Re-installing after deleting node_modules folder inside of your project

rm -rf node_modules

ng update @angular/cli @angular/core

npm i

Comment: Hasn't worked unfortunately...if it's any help versions are below

Angular CLI: 10.0.1
Node: 12.18.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 10.0.3

Comment: A StackBlitz would be helpful if you could provide it